# Change TextInputLayout only hint text style

Tags: android, styles, hint, textstyle

I am trying to change TextInputLayout hint text style to bold. I changed color and other styles of hint in styles with use of **TextAppearance** :

```
 <style name="MyTextInputLayoutTheme" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/black_50</item>
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/green</item>
        <item name="hintAnimationEnabled">false</item>        
    </style>
```

I tried to set

```
<item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
```

or

```
<item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
```

but it doesn't work. Hint text always has style of edit text (if edittext is bold, it automatically has bold hint, if not, the hint is normal) :

[image]